# How can I use .htaccess to load index.html for any URL without redirecting?

Tags: .htaccess, http

I would like to use .htaccess to take URLs like this:

mydomain.com/hello-world

and have the webserver load index.html - but keep the hello-world url intact. So it wouldn't be a redirect, I assume.

Ideally, this would not give a 404 error either.

Is this possible? thanks!!

UPDATE: I think what I'm actually looking for is something that works for any URL, with or without the trailing slash. So...

- mydomain.com
- mydomain.com/hello-world
- mydomain.com/anything-else/

would ALL load index.html, without changing the URL or giving a 404 error. THANK YOU

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Sebleblanc's answer, and that link to the documentation, found what I was looking for was this:

DirectoryIndex /index.html

FallbackResource /index.html

The first line solve it for /hello-world/, the 2nd line does /hello-world

Thanks guys!!

Comment: Don't forget to accept the most relevant answer (even your own, if that's the case)

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex), you only need to add a `DirectoryIndex` directive to your `.htaccess` file.

This directive points to one or more files, which allows you to have redundancy in your index files. Here is an example:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
```

To keep it simple, though, you would need this `.htaccess` file in a directory called "hello-world", so that your users will type `http://example.com/hello-world/` (note the trailing slash) With additional rules (using the `mod_rewrite` module), you may redirect URLs to add a trailing slash to those who lack one.

Comment: Note that as this uses basic Apache features, it still allows you to type `/hello-world/index.html`, and the page will be displayed. If you want to go the extra mile, the code to your site will have to be in a separate folder (or for example in a `cgi-bin` directory) and you will use `<Alias>` directives instead of using directory indexes.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the great info. Adding some clarification to my question now...

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to use the [`Alias` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias).

Suppose the code to your site is in `/home/me/mysite`, and your server root is in `/var/www`:

The `.htaccess` file will go in the `/var/www` directory and will contain these directives:

```
Alias / /home/me/mysite/home.html

Alias /hello-world /home/me/mysite/hello-world.html

Alias /example /home/me/mysite/example.html
```

Using this method, since your server root is basically empty, a user that typed `/hello-wolrd/index.html` will get a 404 page, which might be the expected behavior.